# Large query never reaches remote mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large query. If I run it on localhost it takes 0.01 seconds. If I try it from the remote connection (another server) it never runs at all. The general log shows the connection coming in, and then nothing else. The query also never shows up in slow queries log either. If I run 'show processlist' it shows that there is a connection, but it is sleeping, and info is NULL. Now if I run tcpdump (tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -A port 3306) the query shows up...so I know it is getting to the server, but it's not getting from there to MySQL.

Some settings from my.cnf

```
key_buffer = 32M 
max_allowed_packet = 32M 
query_cache_limit = 1M 
query_cache_size = 16M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M 
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
```

All of those are plenty big enough for the query. It has a IN() and includes about 400 ID's inside of that, but I can't run a IN (SELECT) as the table doesn't exist on that DB. The weirdest part is that it worked fine a couple of weeks ago. They only change I made to my.cnf was:

```
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

(but that just increased the speed of inserts by not logging until the end)

If I shorten the query, it runs. Could it be something limiting in iptables? Maybe some PHP limitation from the server that is connecting to MySQL?

I am totally lost on this, and boxed in pretty good. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the total length of the query including 400 items in an `IN` list exceeds the maximum length for a query now. Just an idea.

Comment: Whether you're using PDO or MySQLi, you need to catch the exception that's being generated (if there is one), or read the error message.  Follow the docs, it's really simple in both cases. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) / [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php)

Comment: can you put a numeric size on "large" for us?

Comment: Most likly you get the exception  "MySQL has gone away"... maybe you also would post some php code?

Comment: @mikeW I pasted the exact query in phpmyadmin from localhost and it worked just fine, so it's not the total length.

Comment: @Leng nothing is showing up in mysql error.log, mysql.log, query.log or apache error.log on either the sending or receiving server.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer 3,904 bytes

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I get no error. If I restart mysql on that server, then I get a lost connection error, but that's the only thing that seems to trigger anything.

Comment: @Brett, it wouldn't show up in your error logs, dude.  You would need to catch the exceptions and echo them out.  Same thing with the errors, you would need to access them in the error objects for whatever wrapper class you're using (PDO/MySQLi) and echo them out.  Without those exceptions and errors, we can't help you.

Comment: I'm catching exceptions and adding them to the logs with error_log($e->getMessage), but nothing is coming up. There is no response from the remote mysql server at all. It connects to it just fine. It is not closing the connection as that is allowed to sleep as checked with show processlist on that server until PHP times out on the sending server or until I restart mysql. With some more testing it seems like anything over 1500 bytes is not being processed by mysql. That does happen to be the tcp packet limit, but it should split up before it is sent or I'd get some buffer overload error

Comment: anything less than 1500 bytes is being processed perfectly and coming back with all the data I need in less than a second.

Comment: It could be a digital ocean issue...it worked until they did their network update two days ago. I am capturing that the query comes in, but it most be getting the data from cache, as I changed tcpdump I noticed that it sent data back. So on the sending server I filtered tcpdump to show only traffic from that IP, and I got some interesting stuff. A lot of "incorrect" flags at first, and then a whole bunch of this: 20:56:57.004591 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.241.xxx.xxx tell 192.241.xxx.xxx, Reply 192.241.xxx.xxx is-at 04:01:05:xx:xx:xx

Comment: It does really look like a routing / tcp problem indeed. Is that `tcpdump` on the client or on the host? And if so, are the packages after the first part of the same TCP session? Is there anything routing there in between, or do client & host just share a dumb switch?

Comment: BTW: that arp should be normal, it just wants to know where machines are on its own subnet. _Unless_ you get different answers for the same IP, in that case: employ arpwatch, it will tell you which machines are battling for IPs.

Comment: What happens if you connect from your php program to the "remote" database, and then issue a trivial query like `SELECT 'hello, world!` ? Does that query complete?  From your php program?

Comment: @OllieJones yes that does work

Comment: @Wrikken, thank you, that was very helpful. As I was watching both dumps on the client and host, the client was making that call every time the host was attempting to send back data. I just heard back from digital ocean and showed them my tcpdumps and they confirmed it is an issue on their end and are working on a fix along with Juniper.